# Problem calling Overpass API with convert statement

Tags: openstreetmap, api, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I try to make an Overpass API call with restricted number of tags, to achieve this I incorporated **convert** statement. Here is working overpass turbo example of query for data I would like to fetch:

```
[out:json][bbox:52.2,20.7,52.3,21.3];
node [amenity=drinking_water];
convert node
    ::id=id(),
    id=id(),
    lat=lat(),
    lon=lon(),
    access=t["access"],
    name=t["name"];
out;
```

Next i tried to make an URL call using this query like this:

```
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?[out:json][bbox:52.2,20.7,52.3,21.3];node[amenity=drinking_water];convert%20node::id=id(),id=id(),lat=lat(),lon=lon(),access=t["access"],name=t["name"];out;
```

Unfortunatelly it throws parse error:

> Error: line 1: parse error: Element class name expected - '%' found.
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: Operator expected, but "node"found.
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: Operator expected, but "access"found.
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: Operator expected, but "name"found.
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: "%" cannot be used as binary operator
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: t[...] needs an argument
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: "%" cannot be used as binary operator
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: t[...] needs an argument
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: if special character "%" is present in
> property name then the property name must be in quotes
>
> Error: line 1: parse error: "=" cannot be used as binary operator
>
> Error: line 1: static error: The attribute type must be set to a
> nonempty string.

I can see, that the problem (or one many) is with dividing convert element with space, but I don't know how to workaround it. Removing space between them results in parse error:

> Error: line 1: parse error: Unknown type "convertnode"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include "data=" in your example query, right after "interpreter?". The following will also work:

```
curl -g 'https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][bbox:52.2,20.7,52.3,21.3];node[amenity=drinking_water];convert%20node::id=id(),id=id(),lat=lat(),lon=lon(),access=t["access"],name=t["name"];out;'
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier there is a method to convert your query directly to an URL. First click on "Export".

[image: The Export button to click.]

This gives you a dialog where you could simply copy the required URL (right-click on "Overpass API"):

[image: The query as an API URL.]

And this is the final URL:
https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%5Bbbox%3A52.2%2C20.7%2C52.3%2C21.3%5D%3B%0Anode%20%5Bamenity%3Ddrinking_water%5D%3B%0Aconvert%20node%0A%20%20%20%20%3A%3Aid%3Did%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20id%3Did%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20lat%3Dlat%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20lon%3Dlon%28%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20access%3Dt%5B%22access%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3Dt%5B%22name%22%5D%3B%0Aout%3B

But don't ask me what the conversion rules are for that but calling that URL gives this JSON:

[image: The final JSON.]